# Dynamically inject different versions of a dependency depending on user data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control

Is it possible to dynamically inject different implementations of a dependency depending on user parameters? What I'm after is something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IRequestService>(s =>
{
    var user = s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User;
    if (user.Claims.Any(c => c.Value == "foo"))
    {
      // resolve and return IRequestService implementation 1
    }
    else
    {
      // resolve and return IRequestService implementation 2
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a great opportunity for a factory.

Comment: Yes. It is often used for multi-tenant applications to switch data context or inject behavior based on request user.

Comment: @RyanWilson right, I guess I could utilize `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` inside the factory function above if I don't want an explicit factory class?

Comment: @filur Or create a factory interface and concreate implementation of the factory and inject the factory where you need to create an `IRequestService`

Comment: I came here to +1 @RyanWilson

Comment: @davidfowl Thank you David. That means a lot coming from a Microsoft employee